# Ellipse and bissector

Tags: geometry

I have a block on the following problem: let an ellipse of foci F and F'.
$(PT_1)$ and $(PT_2)$ are two tangents.
$F_1$ is the symmetric of $F$ by the orthogonal symmetry with the line $(PT_1)$.
$F_2$ is the symmetric of $F$ by the orthogonal symmetry with the line $(PT_2)$.

I have to show that $(PF')$ is the orthogonal bisector of $[F_1 F_2]$. I would have to use the compositions of symmetries, but I don't see where this would lead. Could you give me a little help?
[image: Ellipse]

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Connect $F_1$ to $F_2$ , F to $F_1$ and F to $F_2$. Due to definition of ellipse we have:

$FT_1+F'T_1=F'T_2+FT_2$

$FT_1=F_1T_1$

$FT_2=F_2T_2$

$\Rightarrow F_1T_1+T_1F'=F'T_2+T_2F_2$

That means F' is the midpoint of $F_1F_2$.Also we have:

$\widehat {F_1PT_1}=\widehat {FPT_1}=\widehat {PF'T_2}$

therefore:

$\widehat {F_1PF'}=\widehat {T_1PT_2} $

Also:

$\widehat{FPT_2}=\widehat{F_2PT_2}$

Which finally gives:

$\widehat {F_2PT_2}+\widehat {T_2 P F'}=\widehat {F'PT_1}+\widehat {T_1PF_1}$

OR:

$\widehat {F_1PF'}=\widehat {F'PF_2}$

that is PF' is bisector of $\widehat {F_1PF_2}$